Why is the value of trip_days coming out NULL, when it's being used to calculate DailyCostAverage and it's returning the correct number just fine
i have this procedure where i'm calculating the total cost and daily cost average of a trip depending on the number of days of the trip. i'm using DATEDIFF to calculate trip_days.
i'm just confused why it's coming out as NULL AND YET i'm using it to calculate the daily cost average and it's actually giving the correct answer. thank you!
looks like this:
trip_days is null but daily_cost_average is not. why?
This is the procedure:
DELIMITER //

CREATE PROCEDURE usp_update_activity_cost_get_total_trip_cost( IN activity_id_in INT,IN new_cost_in DECIMAL(10,2),OUT trip_name VARCHAR(255),OUT activity_name VARCHAR(255),OUT current_total_cost DECIMAL(10,2), OUT daily_cost_average DECIMAL(10,2), OUT trip_days INT)

BEGIN DECLARE this_trip_id INT;DECLARE trip_start_date DATE;DECLARE trip_end_date DATE;DECLARE trip_days INT ;


-- retrieve the associated trip_id, trip name, and activity name for the input activity_id
SELECT a.trip_id, t.name, a.name 
INTO this_trip_id, trip_name, activity_name
FROM activities a
JOIN trips t ON a.trip_id = t.trip_id
WHERE a.activity_id = activity_id_in
LIMIT 1;


-- if the activity id exists, update the cost of activity in the activities table
IF activity_id_in IS NOT NULL THEN
    -- update the cost of the activity
    UPDATE activities
    SET cost_in_cad = new_cost_in
    WHERE activity_id = activity_id_in;

    -- calculate the updated total cost for the trip the activity id is associated with
    SELECT SUM(cost_in_cad) 
    INTO current_total_cost
    FROM activities
    WHERE trip_id = this_trip_id 
    LIMIT 1;

    -- retrieve the trip's start and end dates to use it for calculating the number of days of the trip
    SELECT start_date, end_date 
    INTO trip_start_date, trip_end_date
    FROM trips
    WHERE trip_id = this_trip_id
    LIMIT 1;

    -- calculate the total number of days of the trip
    -- adding 1 so that if both start and end dates are on the same day, the days won't be zero
    
    SET trip_days = DATEDIFF(trip_end_date, trip_start_date) + 1;

    -- calculate the daily cost average using current total cost and number of days of the trip
    SET daily_cost_average = current_total_cost / trip_days;
 
ELSE
    -- if the activity id does not exist, set all outputs to NULL
    SET trip_name = NULL;
    SET activity_name = NULL;
    SET current_total_cost = NULL;
    SET daily_cost_average = NULL;
    SET trip_days = NULL;
END IF;

END //

DELIMITER ; 

i tried changing the data type of trip_days many times, but it's still returning NULL.  i tried with different values and it's still the same.
i also tried on my friend's computer and he's also getting NULL
this is how i'm using it:
SET @activity_id_in = 1;
SET @new_cost_in = 250.00;
SET @trip_name = NULL;
SET @activity_name = NULL;
SET @current_total_cost = NULL;
SET @daily_cost_average = NULL;
SET @trip_days = NULL;

CALL usp_update_activity_cost_get_total_trip_cost(
    @activity_id_in, @new_cost_in, 
    @trip_name, @activity_name, @current_total_cost, @daily_cost_average, @trip_days
);

SELECT 
    @trip_name AS TripName,
    @activity_name AS ActivityName,
    @current_total_cost AS TotalTripCost,
    @daily_cost_average AS DailyCostAverage,
    @trip_days AS TripDays;

thank you so much!!

Try NOT using the same names for declared variables and parameters..And provide sample data which illustrates our assertation.

When the column and the variable have the same name and there is no tablename alias in the identifier then the variable is used unconditionally.

CREATE PROCEDURE usp_update_activity_cost_get_total_trip_cost(
  ...
  OUT trip_days INT
)
BEGIN
  ...
  DECLARE trip_days INT;

You have an output variable named trip_days and a local variable also named trip_days.
  SET trip_days = DATEDIFF(trip_end_date, trip_start_date) + 1;

This sets the local variable of that name, not the OUT variable.
You don't actually need the local variable trip_days at all.
Just remove that DECLARE:
  DECLARE trip_days INT; -- remove this line

Of if you think you need the local variable, rename either the local variable or the OUT variable so they are not the same. Then assign the value of your DATEDIFF to the OUT variable, and use that in the subsequent calculation of daily_cost_average.
Then the procedure works and outputs a non-NULL value for trip_days.

I see what you're saying, thank you so much, I will give it another go!
